# Destructured variables not visible inside of function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having this input

```
const register = () => {
...

return (
   <Input
    name="password"
    type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"}
    placeholder={t('placeholder.pass')}
    onChange={setFirst}
    onFocus={() => setIsMyInputFocused(true)}
    onBlur={() => setIsMyInputFocused(false)}
    validations={[validatePassword]}
   />
 );
}
```

and **above** this I have a password validator

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState({
    firstPassword: ""
  });

  const [
    validLength,
    hasNumber,
    upperCase,
    specialChar,
  ] = usePasswordValidation({
    firstPassword: password.firstPassword
  });

  const setFirst = (event) => {
    setPassword({ ...password, firstPassword:event.target.value });
  };
```

the states for validLength, hasNumber, upperCase and specialChar are updated in a different component like this

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const usePasswordValidation = ({ firstPassword = "" }) => {
const [validLength, setValidLength] = useState(null);
const [hasNumber, setHasNumber] = useState(null);
const [upperCase, setUpperCase] = useState(null);
const [specialChar, setSpecialChar] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidLength(firstPassword.length >= 8 ? true : false);
    setUpperCase(firstPassword.toLowerCase() !== firstPassword);
    setHasNumber(/\d/.test(firstPassword));
    setSpecialChar(/[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\]{};':"\\|,.<>?~]/.test(firstPassword));
  }, [firstPassword]);

  return [validLength, hasNumber, upperCase, specialChar];
};
```

**The question is, how can I also output an message if not all the requirements are met?**

I've tried like this:

```
<p style={validLength && hasNumber && upperCase && specialChar ? errorMessage : noError} role="alert">
  Your password does not meet all the requirements. Please check it again.
</p>
```

But this is not working since is not directly connected to the input so it won't go away when the input is empty - so in this situation I have two errors overlapping: one with filed required and the one for password check.

I've also tried this - a function that is called in the validation HTML attr. of the input.
It listens to the input value but it cannot see the outside states of validLength, hasNumber etc.

```
const validatePassword = (value) => {
  if (!validLength && !hasNumber && !upperCase && !specialChar) {
  return ( 
  <p style={errorMessage} role="alert">
     Your password does not meet all the requirements. Please check it again.
   </p>
  );
 }
};
```

Can I somehow create a condition inside the function based on the states of the requirements?

What I'm missing? I think it's easy fix but I'm too blind or I don't have enough experience with React and/or Hooks or all of the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to do conditional rendering. You can put this into return of your functional component:

```js
{
    (!validLength || !hasNumber || !upperCase || !specialChar) && 
    (<p>Your password does not meet all the requirements. Please check it again.</p>)
}
```

I think the issue was that you weren't checking the validity correctly, your error message showed up only if none of the validators was set to `true`.

The whole return would then look like:

```
return (
<>
   <Input
    name="password"
    type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"}
    placeholder={t('placeholder.pass')}
    onChange={setFirst}
    onFocus={() => setIsMyInputFocused(true)}
    onBlur={() => setIsMyInputFocused(false)}
    validations={[validatePassword]}
   />
    {(!validLength || !hasNumber || !upperCase || !specialChar) && 
    (<p>Your password does not meet all the requirements. Please check it again.</p>)}
</>
 );
}
```

You can replace fragment with `div` if you need to.

If you want to know more about conditional rendering, read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply. so this works but works exactly as my first example: it disables the error when all the conditions are met, but it's not disabling it when the input is empty or when you go first time on the page

Comment: You can add `&& password.firstPassword` into the condition if you want it to hide, when the input is empty or null

Comment: I was trying to add that to your example and that\s why I was having the weird result. I just added  && password.firstPassword to my first example and it's working. I think so far this solves it